# Adjektiv und Adverb Kombination in "serviert traditionell spanische Gerichte"

Tags: adjective, adverb

> Das Restaurant "Sobrino de Botín" in Madrid serviert traditionell spanische Gerichte.

Bedeutet dieser Satz (a) oder (b)?

> (a) The restaurant "Sobrino de Botín" in Madrid serves traditional Spanish dishes.
>
> (b) The restaurant "Sobrino de Botín" in Madrid traditionally serves Spanish dishes.

Comment: Name und Madrid tragen wenig zur Unterscheidung bei - die könnte man rauskürzen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es kann (b) oder (c) bedeuten, d.h. das Adverb kann sich auf das Verb oder auf das Adjektiv *spanische* beziehen:

> (b) The restaurant "Sobrino de Botín" in Madrid traditionally serves Spanish dishes.
>   (c) The restaurant "Sobrino de Botín" in Madrid serves traditionally Spanish dishes.

Für die Bedeutung (a) bräuchte man ein Adjektiv: *traditionelle spanische Gerichte*.

Wenn man klarstellen will, daß (b) gemeint ist, könnte man *traditionell* durch *traditionellerweise* ersetzen (oder den Satz umstellen). Um deutlich zu machen, daß es (c) sein soll, muß man den Satz umstellen:

> Traditionell spanische Gerichte serviert das Restaurant "Sobrino de Botín" in Madrid.

Comment: b) heißt doch, dass das Restaurant schon immer solche Gerichte serviert, `traditional, Spanish dishes` wären spanische, traditionelle Gerichte. Traditionell spanische Gerichte kommt mir spanisch vor. Sind das Gerichte die früher Spanisch waren, aber heute nicht mehr? `Spanische Gerichte traditionell serviert` könnte moderne, molekulare Küche sein, aber der Ober hat einen Sombrero auf.

Comment: Für b) auch möglich: "Spanische Gerichte serviert das Restaurant traditionell"

Comment: @Em: das sehe ich anders, denn: "Spanische Gerichte serviert das Restaurant heiß/kalt/mit Salat."..also... wie serviert das Restaurant? Das "traditionell" im Sinne von traditionellerweise passt nicht wirklich in diese Adverbgruppe, wenn du weißt was ich meine.